# PyQt5 - What does "&" symbol mean in the name of menu bar?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

When I look for explanation of "QMenuBar" in websites (for example, http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/menusandtoolbars/), the name of a menu always has "&" symbol. What is the meaning of "&" symbol?

Comment: Why didn't you just look at the Qt docs for [QMenuBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#details)?

Answer (score 3):

It specifies the hot key or shortcut for the menu option.

In the zetcode example, on Windows the Alt key activates the menu bar, and he uses &File, meaning Alt-F would select the file menu.

The letter that follows the ampersand is the hot key.